# Can i use infopath 2013 designer to design and manage infopath forms on SharePoint 2010

Tags: infopath

Can I use the Infopath Designer 2013 to design and manage infopath on SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Did you get any answer. my client is migrating from office 2010 to office 365 with SharePoint version still in 2010. Will it have any issue with my already code enabled info path form

Comment: No answer.Download SP 2010 Designer for your SP 2010 environment.After migration open your SP 2013 infopath forms with SP 2013 Designer